# Create array inside array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am trying to create  a tree of elements like below:

```
Div 1-1
  Div 2-1
Div 1-2
  div 2-2
    div 3-1
    div 4-1
```

and so on..
What I need to do is to create array with sub arrays and push all elements of the div.

```
 for (var i = 1 ; i <= 4; i++){

        var headers =  new Array();
        var siblings = new Array();
        var j = 1;

    $( ".header"+i ).each(function() {
                $('.fr-placeholder').remove();
                var txt = $(this).text();
                $(this).attr('id', 'header'+i+'-'+j);

                siblings.push([i,j]);
                j++;

                if(txt.length != 0){
                    var divId = $(this).attr('id');
                    $('#outline').append('<li><a data-id="'+divId+'" >'+txt+'</a></li>' );
                }


    });
    headers.push(siblings);

 }
```

But I need to do this for all sub -elements and create array inside array inside array... Any help?

Comment: Just a suggestion about naming your divs. You should keep a hierarchical way of naming them. For instance. `div-1 div-2   div-1-1 div-1-1-1 div 1-1-2`. Each number representing the level. It's not logic to have `2-1` a child of 1-1.

Comment: they are not saved in hierarchical way  they are not div inside div but all separate divs.

Comment: To create an array of array is easy. You can put whatever you want in an array. I don't understand th elink between your code, yours divs tag and the question. Anyway, here's for you http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp